# Azure website - minimizing small frequent outages

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got a SaaS product hosted on azure. I have a separate .net web app and  simple marketing site, both hosted as websites on azure. Both were set to one instance, with auto-scale configured.

I'm concerned about small frequent outages that happen to my websites. Azure say to expect about 10 mins a week, and that's within the SLA, but I want to minimize this as much as possible.

So, for my marketing site, I changed the instance count to 2 and removed the auto-scale. From what I read, having 2 instances should really help with any issues - as azure [say themselves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh744832.aspx):

> Note that Azure Websites already provides failover load balancing functionality for websites within a datacenter (also known as a region), regardless of the website mode.

Which sounds great. BUT... It's currently making no difference. I've got pingdom monitoring both the marketing site and the main app, and I've had 2 2-min outages this morning. Both the sites had exactly the same issues and were resolved at the same time.

Am I expecting too much? All the docs suggest this is a good strategy (short of the traffic routing manager) for mitigating this.

Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem. Standard tier Website with AlwaysOn configured and 2 instance at all times keeps getting short  outages daily.

Answer (score 0):

What scale mode are you running in? If -Basic or- Standard, have you turned on the "Always On" flag?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-web-sites-adds-always-on/

Comment: Standard, and yes always-on is on

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question is a little bit popular, so I'm posting an update - one year later...

My observations thus far:

The outages that I experienced about a year ago have mostly (but not entirely) stopped. I think that most of them were things changing in Azure, and knocking the site out for a few mins here and there - recently I haven't had anything like these issues. I have changed quite a lot though since then...

1. I always make sure that anything even slightly long running is moved out into a queue
2. I make sure I employ a retry strategy for talking to external services, to make the app more resilient.
3. I don't run on more than 1 instance unless I need the throughput - it generally doesn't help with resilience wrt the issue I originally posted about.
4. I run one "large" instance now. Since I went large, I seem to get much less issues. Maybe this in part is because of the VMs improved start up speed, or additional RAM/CPU which makes it more able to cope with issues, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

One option to get higher availability is to create two identical sites in two different regions and use Azure Traffic Manager to failover from one site to the other in case one of them goes down.